# Program to calculate supremum of a given number

Tags: java

So my question is to get a number as an input (number should not have duplicate digits) and the program should find the smallest number between the larger numbers of input by swapping the digits :||

example:

129 -- (192), 912, 921, 291

32874 -- (34278), 47823, 43278

123456 -- (123465), 132465, 321645

i tried this for a 10 digit number but it didn't work

```
public static long findSup(long num) {

    int[] digits = new int[10];

    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {

        long temp = (num % 10);
        digits[i] = (int) temp;
        num /= 10;

    }

    boolean stop = false;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0 && !stop; i--) {

        for (int j = 8; j >= 0 && !stop; j--) {

            if (digits[i] > digits[j]) {
                int temp = digits[j];
                digits[j] = digits[i];
                digits[i] = temp;

                int min = Math.min(i, j);

                for (int k = 9; k > min; k--) {
                    for (int l = 8; l > min; l--) {
                        if (digits[k] < digits[l]) {
                            temp = digits[k];
                            digits[k] = digits[l];
                            digits[l] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                stop = true;
            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        result =  (long) (result + (Math.pow(10, j++) * digits[i]));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach for this problem (assuming positive numbers) is to:

1. covert the value into an array of digits;
2. get all the combinations of those digits;
3. sort those combinations.
4. get the smallest possible number greater than the value passed as parameter;

A running example:

```
public class Supremun {

    public static String toString(int [] digits) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int a : digits) {
            result.append(a);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static void swap(int[] input, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = input[a];
        input[a] = input[b];
        input[b] = tmp;
    }


    public static void combinations(int n, int [] elements, List<int[]> combinations) {
        if(n == 1)
            combinations.add(elements.clone());
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
                combinations(n - 1, elements, combinations);
                if(n % 2 == 0) swap(elements, i, n-1);
                else swap(elements, 0, n-1);
            }
            combinations(n - 1, elements, combinations);
        }
    }

    public static long findSup(long num) {
        int[] digits =  Long.toString(num).chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
        List<int[]> comb = new ArrayList<>();
        combinations(digits.length, digits, comb);
        long[] possible_values = comb.stream().map(array -> toString(array)).mapToLong(Long::parseLong).toArray();
        Arrays.sort(possible_values);
        for(int i = 0; i < possible_values.length - 1; i++){
            if(possible_values[i] == num){
                return possible_values[i+1];
            }
        }
        return -1; // undefined
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(findSup(129));
      System.out.println(findSup(32874));
      System.out.println(findSup(123456));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
192
34278
123465
```

Answer (score 0):

per your definition, a supremum can only exist, if either the first digit is not the biggest possible number of those in your input OR otherwise if this is valid for the remains, if you remove the first digit. Example:

- input 98 has no sup, 89 has 98
- input 981 has no sup, 918 has one, because 18 has 81 as as sup.

So you could recursively check the sequence of digits.